# How to insert a value for each date between a start date and an end date?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerquery

I create a Power BI Report. I have a dataset that contains deals with a start date, an end date, and a daily rate.

| Deal | Deal Start | Deal end | Daily rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Deal 1 | 27/02/2023 | 02/03/2023 | 580$ |
| Deal 2 | 01/03/2023 | 03/03/2023 | 480$ |
| Deal 3 | 06/03/2023 | 08/03/2023 | 300$ |

I want to plot the total average per month of the daily rate of the different contracts. Therefore, I would like to duplicate all the daily rates for all **the working days** between the start date of the deal and its end date. **How can I do this in Power BI?**

I have tried to create a table with all the dates over a certain period and all I can manage to do is display the value for the start date only (and not all the dates between it and the end date).

What I expect is this:

| Date | Daily rate |
| --- | --- |
| 27/02/2023 | 580$ |
| 28/02/2023 | 580$ |
| 01/03/2023 | 580$ |
| 01/03/2023 | 480$ |
| 02/03/2023 | 580$ |
| 02/03/2023 | 480$ |
| 03/03/2023 | 480$ |
| 04/03/2023 | 0 |
| 05/03/2023 | 0 |
| 06/03/2023 | 300$ |
| 07/03/2023 | 300$ |
| 08/03/2023 | 300$ |

Comment: This feels like https://xyproblem.info/. What is the final visualisation or outcome you plan for this data? Filling in blanks is an option but it might not be the right approach.

Comment: Did anyone's answers or comments help you?

Comment: Yes, the comment solve the problem !

Answer (score 0):

To me, your desired format seems very odd, but you could do it with a small bit of M

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Date", each {Number.From([Deal Start])..Number.From([Deal end])}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Date"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Deal Start", "Deal end", "Deal"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]